# how to analyse P6spy log live and from log files?

Tags: p6spy

With old version 1.3 of p6spy.jar you could plug the irontrack UI live and also read spy.log afterwards to analyse SQL activity.

What tool could do the same with p6spy version 2.x.x format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research, one good way to go is to use Logstash to import the p6spy v2.3 logs into Elasticsearch and then query with ViewSense or make dashboards with Kibana. ELK could be used in many other places, so it's a good tool to learn

Comment: i also found the open-source http://www.stagemonitor.org/  which is very interesting for performance metrics